# Proper way to push_back pointer to a vector

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

I have a `ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks` due to a constructor of a class using a vector of pointers.

Here I simply my code.

---

**Problem.h**

```
class Problem {
 protected:
    std::vector<const Object*> pointer_vector;

 public:
    // Constructor
    Problem();
};
```

---

**Problem.cc**

```
Problem::Problem() {
    this->pointer_vector.push_back(new Object(parameter_list_1));
    this->pointer_vector.push_back(new Object(parameter_list_2));
    // here I just want to push back the pointer into the vector
}
```

---

Since my code still works. But I got the `ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks` as I mentioned.

I think I did something wrong with the `push_back` and I am asking about the proper way to do that.
The thing is **I want to ask some general way to solve that.** Like
    How can I improve this code using the `raw pointer`.

Because I think we have certainly beautiful way to solve that and not **found** possible duplicates. If you need detailed error reporting, I will add them.

Thanks!

Comment: Show a [mcve]. There's no double-free in the code you've shown. The problem is somewhere in the code you haven't shown.

Comment: `std::vector<Object>` is probably sufficient for you. Else `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<const Object>>`.

Comment: Ok. I deleted the things that is not relevant here. Thanks for advise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't overthink this.

It seems that everything you have in your object gets allocated there, so use smart pointers:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>> pointer_vector;
```

Comment: Why do you want to handle memory yourself if there is no need to? That's the point of smart pointers, you ensure there is no memory leaks.

Comment: Let me guess... School assignment with idiotic rules? :)

Answer (score 3):

Every object that you create with `new` will have to be `delete`ed at some point. It's your responsibility to do that. In your case the easiest solution is to add it in the destructor for your `Problem` class.

```
Problem::~Problem() {
    for (auto ptr : pointer_vector)
        delete ptr;
}
```

If you ever remove objects from the vector, you have to make sure that they are `delete`d there as well.

**Please Note:** the proper way to do this is however to use smart pointers as Matthieu already said in his answer.